# How to use braces {} of PHP inside XML?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to do something like this in PHP and XML

```
for($counter=0;<$Num;$counter++)
{
    $Line=$counter+1;
    if($counter==0)
    {
        $data =  '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
                <request>
                <GRP ID="1">
                <FLD NAM="TRANSACTION" TYP="Char">'.$transaction.'</FLD>
                </GRP>
    }//I want to close this bleces of PHP which is located inside of XML


    <TAB DIM="1" ID="1" SIZE="1">
    <LIN NUM=' . $Line . '>
    <FLD NAM="ITEMREFERENCE">' . $itemCode[$counter] . '</FLD>
    </LIN>
    </TAB>
    </request>
}
```

How can I use that braces inside of XML?

Comment: do what? What brace? What's your actual issue/error?

Comment: Difficult to spot what you are trying to do for all the TYPO's can you clean that up? Or is that the actual PHP code you are using

Comment: `PHP` and `XML` are __distinct entities__. You cannot close braces in xml and expect that php code will understand it

Comment: FIX:1:: `for($counter=0;$counter<$Num;$counter++)`

Comment: What I want to do is to use loop where first loop will execute all XML tags, but the second loop or N loop will execute only one tag of xml(lines).

Comment: Thank you Riggs, if it's impossible how can I use for loop inside XML tags where I can loop only XML tags of line without condition of IF, Because PHP does not work inside XML tags

Comment: Please learn how to create XML using either SimpleXML or DOMDocument, creating your own is prone to errors and especially when nesting elements can be problematic (at the least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` and `XML` are **distinct entities**. You cannot close braces in xml and expect that php code will understand it. I presume you need something like this:

```
$data = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
    <request>
        <GRP ID="1">
            <FLD NAM="TRANSACTION" TYP="Char">'.$transaction.'</FLD>
        </GRP>';

for ($counter=0;$counter<$Num;$counter++) {
    $Line=$counter+1;
    $data .= '
    <TAB DIM="1" ID="1" SIZE="1">
        <LIN NUM=' . $Line . '>
            <FLD NAM="ITEMREFERENCE">' . $itemCode[$counter] . '</FLD>
        </LIN>
    </TAB>';
}
$data .= '</request>';

echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this using SimpleXML may look long - but it saves any worries about formatting and other issues from building strings.

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
                <request />');
$grp = $doc->addChild("GRP");
$grp->addAttribute("ID", "1");
$fld = $grp->addChild("FLD", $transaction);
$fld->addAttribute("NAM", "TRANSACTION");
$fld->addAttribute("TYP", "Char");
for($counter=0;$counter<$Num;$counter++)    {
    $tab = $doc->addChild("TAB");
    $tab->addAttribute("DIM", "1");
    $tab->addAttribute("ID", "1");
    $tab->addAttribute("SIZE", "1");
    $lin = $tab->addChild("LIN");
    $lin->addAttribute("NUM", (string)($counter+1));
    $fld = $tab->addChild("FLD", $itemCode[$counter]);
    $fld->addAttribute("NAM", "ITEMREFERENCE");
}

echo $doc->asXML();
```